# How to undo replace performed by regex?

Tags: java, regex

In java, I have the following regex `([\\(\\)\\/\\=\\:\\|,\\,\\\\])` which is compiled and then used to escape each of the special characters `()/=:|,\` with a backslash as follows `escaper.matcher(value).replaceAll("\\\\$1")`

So the string `"A/C:D/C"` would end up as `"A\/C\:D\/C"`

Later on in the process, I need to undo that replace. That means I need to match on the combination of `\(`, `\)`, `\/` etc. and replace it with the character immediately following the backslash character.  A backslash followed by any other character should not be matched and there could be cases where a special character will exist without the preceeding backslash, in which case it shouldn't match either.

Since I know all of the cases I could do something like

```
myString.replaceAll("\\(", "(").replaceAll("\\)", ")").replaceAll("\\/", "/")...
```

but I wonder if there is a simpler regex that would allow me to perform the replace for all the special characters in a single step.

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think _"I know, I'll use regular expressions."_ Now they have two problems. -  Jamie Zawinski

Comment: Yes, I've heard that one before and generally agree...

Comment: I too have heard that one before, and generally make a rude noise.

Comment: Can't you just store the original string and use that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems pretty straightforward.  If this were your original code (excess escapes removed):

```
Pattern escaper = Pattern.compile("([()/=:|,\\\\])");

String escaped = escaper.matcher(original).replaceAll("\\\\$1");
```

...the opposite would be:

```
Pattern unescaper = Pattern.compile("\\\\([()/=:|,\\\\])");

String unescaped = unescaper.matcher(escaped).replaceAll("$1");
```

If you weren't escaping and unescaping backslashes themselves (as you're doing), you would have problems, but this should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know java regex flavor but this work with PCRE

replace `\\` followed by (`[()/=:|,\\]`) by $1

in perl you can do

```
$str =~ s#\\([()/=:|,\\])#$1#g;
```

Comment: Yup.  Java is slightly more verbose about it, but the process is the same. ;)